# How much does rerolling improve your odds

Tags: statistics, game-theory, dice

I have been playing a lot of dice based games and re-rolling has been a major mechanic in a lot of them. knowing when to re-roll and just keep what is currently face up seemed like a basic stats problem.

Lets say I had a $6$ sided die each with a unique numeric side. There would then be a $1$ in $6$ chance I roll any one side. Lets also say I wanted to get the highest/best side possible. In the first roll I would have a $1/6$ chance with $5$ undesirable outcomes, and $1$ desirable.

If I re-rolled would the number of total undesirable outcome be as simple as $5^2$ and the total number of desirable out comes be $2$? Thus making my odds of succeeding ($1$ out of $6$ odds) + ($2$ out of $25$ odds)?

Comment: If your goal is "*best side or bust*" then you can simplify the thought process by instead rolling two dice and keeping the best... there are $6^2=36$ different outcomes, $11$ of which have you rolling a six on at least one of the two faces.  You could just as well have written this as $\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}$ if you insisted (*implying the thought process of "get a six on the first die" + "miss on the first die and 'reroll it' and get a six on the second die"*).

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to think about it is as follows:

Your probability of landing a 6 if allowed n-rerolls is 1 - the probability that you fail all rolls.

ie.

$P(\text{A 6 within n rolls}) = 1 - (5/6)^n$

As a quick table:

| n | $P(\text{A 6 within n rolls})$ | decimal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/6 | 0.1667 |
| 2 | 11/36 | 0.3056 |
| 3 | 91/216 | 0.4213 |
| ... | ... | ... |

And as a graph:

[image]

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense if i was looking for the top 2 best would it be 1 -(4/6)^n then?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

No. There are two ways to calculate this.

One way is to consider the events sequentially. In the first roll, you have a 1/6 chance of success (at which point you stop rolling) and a 5/6 chance of failure (in which case you roll again). The second roll has the same 1/6 chance of success. Letting $S_1$ and $S_2$ be the events of the first and second roll succeeding respectively, and $S$ be overall success. Then we have
$$
P(S) = P(S_1) + P(\neg S_1)P(S_2) = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{5}{6}\frac{1}{6} = \frac{11}{36}.
$$
For further rerolls, you could continue this process and get a geometric series.

The other is to consider the die rolling event as a whole. Let's say it's a standard d6 and 6 is the successful face. The setup appears to have one or two die rolls depending on whether the first roll is a 6, but it is equivalent for you to roll the die again if the first roll is a 6 and ignore the result. Therefore, this situation is equivalent to rolling the die twice and seeing if either roll is a 6. Of the 36 equally likely pairs of die rolls, 11 have at least one 6 in them. So the success probability is again 11/36.

11/36 is 83% bigger than 1/6, meaning you nearly double your odds by having a reroll. This has diminishing returns, though, and no matter how many rerolls you get, there's always a chance you could fail all of them.